# Get a finite list of IP addresses for my Heroku App?

Tags: heroku

I have client who wants to send a GET request to my Heroku application. They have asked for a list of IP address to whitelist for egress on their firewall.

I realize this could change weekly or more often, but is it possible to get a finite list of IPs my Heroku app could be on?

I saw the following excerpt on a [Google Groups page for Heroku](http://www.mail-archive.com/heroku@googlegroups.com/msg09210.html), but I could not find it corroborated anywhere else or how to see the list of addresses my app uses.

> Right now your CNAME setup will round-robin between 8 or so IP addresses, and we find

If the list of IP addresses is virtually infinite, do you have any other suggestions for receiving the "GET" request through a firewall economically?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, Heroku will not give you even a range of IP addresses - they can, may and will move dynos between Amazon zones as needs require.

Your only option would be some sort of proxy node with a static IP that they talk to that securely communicates to your Heroku app - or consider if Heroku is the right fit for you here altogether.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I suspected. I will talk to the client about a proxy server.

Answer (score 13):

Heroku runs on amazon ec2, so its [official IP-ranges](https://ip-ranges.amazonaws.com/ip-ranges.json)  should contain all IP-address available to heroku.

Answer (score 7):

You can route outbound traffic through quite expensive `Proximo` add-on to achieve that.

Comment: Man, Proximo is so expensive.

Comment: Now you have other similar add-ons as well: [`QuotaGuard Static`](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/quotaguardstatic) and  [`Fixie`](https://elements.heroku.com/addons/fixie)